# for loop, cant get data from database, django

Tags: django, templates, for-loop

I have couple of jurnal edditions with corresponds to some years. To get the data from the database i have wrote a view

def arkchive(request):

```
years = {}
for year in YearPub.objects.all().order_by('year_alias'):
    years[year.yearpub_int] = {}
    for vipusk in Vipusk.objects.all():
        years[year.yearpub_int][vipusk.vipusk_alias] = Vipusk.objects.filter(vipusk_year=year).order_by('vipusk_alias')

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['years'] = sorted(years.items())
return render_to_response('arkchive.html', args)
```

I have created a model wich looks like this:

```
class Vipusk(models.Model):
    vipusk_int = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Номер випуску')
    vipusk_alias = models.SlugField(verbose_name='АЛИАС випуску')
    vipusk_year = models.ForeignKey(YearPub, verbose_name='Випуск/ГОД ')


class Meta:
    ordering = ['vipusk_alias']
    verbose_name = 'Номер випуску'
    verbose_name_plural = u'Номери випусків'

def __str__(self):
    return '№ ({})'.format(self.vipusk_alias)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '№ ({})'.format(self.vipusk_alias)
```

And the part of the code that corresponds to visualization from the database

```
{% for year, vipusks in years %}
    <div class = 'pub_year'>{{year.year_int}}</div>
    {% for vipusk in vipusks %}
        <li class='jurnal_item'><a href='/main/zmist/{{year.year_int}}/{{vipusk.vipusk_alias}}/'>№ {{vipusk.vipusk_id}}({{vipusk.vipusk_alias}})</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But as soon as i run the application, my html template shows nothing.Please give me a hint where is my mistake

Comment: What version of django are you using? `render_to_response` is a kind of old way to render a template

Comment: i am using 1.9.11

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution 
in view file it is suppose to be

```
years = {}
    for year in YearPub.objects.all().order_by('year_alias'):
        years[year.yearpub_int] = Vipusk.objects.filter(vipusk_year=year).order_by('id')
```